# Using Pdf Form field to locate and resize SignHereTab

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

My goal is to make **SignHereTab** location and size the same as one of my Pdf Form Field. Docusign guide
tells me that I can transform Pdf Form fields into DocuSign tabs. And according to the guide I shoud use **CompositeTempates**.

I have two recipients and two Pdfs. One pdf should be signed by both recipients, the second pdf should be signed by the first. Here is JSON example of envelop. I'm usign CreateEnvelop method from **Docusign.eSign.dll** (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/)

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "base64 data",
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "MainPart.pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "True"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "accessCode": "1239",
                "email": "insured@gmail.com",
                "name": "Insured ",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "recipientId": "1",
                      "tabLabel": "insured_sign_parta\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "accessCode": "1212",
                "email": "owner@gmail.com",
                "name": "Owner",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "recipientId": "2",
                      "tabLabel": "owner_sign_parta\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "base64 data",
        "documentId": "2",
        "name": "AdditionalPart.pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "True"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "accessCode": "1239",
                "email": "insured@gmail.com",
                "name": "Insured",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "recipientId": "1",
                      "tabLabel": "insured_sign_parta\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailBlurb": "Email Text",
  "emailSubject": "Subject",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

When I open documents SignHereTabs doesn't appear :(

Could anybody help me, please? What am I doing wrong?
I have seen tutorials from Docusign website and all related issues on StackOverflow, but still it didn't help. I've been investigating this issue for almost two days and I got nothing...

Answer (score 0):

tabs should have a documentId as well as a recipientId so that they can refer to both the recipient that needs to sign them and the specific document that they should be in. 
see here for full reference - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs